# Graph usage pattern for RNNs

Tags: tensorflow

I am confused about the lifetime of tensors/ops/variables inside the default graph.

In RNNs, the graph structure will change on each iteration due to the variable length of input data. Should separate graphs thus be created/destroyed on each iteration of training to accommodate the changing structure of the graph, or is there a way to stick with the default graph?

Also, if new graphs are constructed, how can they share variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For RNNs specifically, there are two options: `tf.nn.rnn`, and `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`.  Neither one creates or destroys graphs temporarily.

The first function creates `T` subgraphs, where `T` is the length of the python list of inputs you provide (that is, inputs is a len `T` python list of shape `[batch, depth]` tensors).  `tf.nn.rnn` always expects a fixed number of time steps.  Note, you can control *which* subgraphs are run for a given step by passing the `sequence_length` parameter; the function then uses conditional evaluation (`tf.cond`) to determine what operations get run.

In contrast, `dynamic_rnn` uses a special TensorFlow while loop and other trickery that introduces a limited type of loop in the graph structure.  In this case, there is exactly one subgraph for the "time step", and it gets run over and over until your input has been processed.  In this case your input is a `3D` tensor with dimensions `[batch, time, depth]` (it can be `[time, batch, depth]` if you set `time_major=True`); and the first two dimensions can vary from step to step.